# Laravel Pagination

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-pagination

How can I create a pagination in laravel?

**My Model**

**Post**

```
function comments() {

    return $this->hasMany('Comment')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

**Comment**

```
function posts(){

    return $this->belongsTo('Post');
}
```

**User**

```
function posts(){

    return $this->hasMany('Post');
}


function comments(){

    return $this->hasMany('Comment');
}
```

UserController

```
$user = User::find(1); //this will give me all the user's post and comment details

//i know I can do  $user = User::paginate(30) to get 30 user per page
```

**What I want to Achieve**

I want to create a pagination of 10 comment per page.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options: you can call `paginate()` on the relationship query, or you can manually create a paginator.

Call `paginate()` on the relationship query (uses the relationship function):

```
$user = User::find(1);
$comments = $user->comments()->paginate(10);
```

Manually create a paginator (uses the relationship attribute):

```
$user = User::find(1);
$paginator = Paginator::make($user->comments, $user->comments->count(), 10);
```

Pagination documentation can be found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination).

Comment: Hi @patricus thanks for quick response. Is there any way i can user paginate in model?

Comment: @CannotFindSymbol I'm sorry, but I am not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

$only10comments = User::with('comments')->paginate(10);

If you use next, previous links in pagination, then use simplePaginate.

$only10comments = User::with('comments')->simplePaginate(10);

Hope this helps.