# Column Level Cursor pagination in PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using `Laravel version 5.2`. As its having large amount of data, I am using cursor `pagiations` as below table having `primary id` and `name` fields

```
for page 1 -> select * from table LIMIT 10

For page 2 -> select * from table where id < $lastpagelastementID LIMIT 10
```

As the same way, if we sort by the `name` column, How can we handle this `cursor pagination`? 
Is there any option to do this?

we can use Laravel pagination as Explained in

[Laravel Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534867/laravel-pagination)

But i need a Cursor Pagination as above. Can any one help me to find solutions?

Comment: @Shadow, i am not asking about laravel basic pagination? please read and understand my question

Comment: There you go, added a plain sql pagination duplicate as well.

Comment: @Shadow, I have editted my Question Title and Description? Please understand my questions

Comment: @Shadow Both Questions doesnot having enough/Correct Answer for my Question.  i need a pagination of data without using paginate() of function in laravel and not using Primary id < or > last id

Comment: @Shadow, Could you please show me the exact answer for this question? or let others to answer this questions please? plesae remove the duplicate tag

Comment: I added a 2nd duplicate link - although I do not understand why you cannot use laravel's pagination. It does exactly the same thing behind the scenes.

Comment: @Shadow, the 2duplicate link you added doesnot having enough answers. if i use normal pagination there may be duplicate record at the start of the next page for new records added behind when i am in 1st page. Without understanding my question you have marked as it is duplicate :(

Comment: @Shadow, Please look into this