# Cursor Pagination in PHP with a Column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using `Laravel version 5.2`. As its having large amount of data, I am using cursor `pagiations` as below table having `primary id` and `name` fields

```
for page 1 -> select * from table LIMIT 10

For page 2 -> select * from table where id < $lastpagelastementID LIMIT 10
```

As the same way, if we sort by the `name` column, How can we handle this `cursor pagination`? 
Is there any option to do this?

we can use Laravel pagination as Explained in

[Laravel Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534867/laravel-pagination)

But i need a Cursor Pagination as above. Can any one help me to find solutions?

Comment: I think you should use ajax to fetch the next page records in json format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install this package via composer using:

```
composer require juampi92/cursor-pagination
```

**Config**

To publish the config file to `config/cursor_pagination.php` run:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Juampi92\CursorPagination\CursorPaginationServiceProvider" --tag="config"
```

**How does it work**

The main idea behind a cursor pagination is that it needs a context to know what results to show next. So instead of saying `page=2`, you say `next_cursor=10`. The result is the same as the old fashioned page pagination, but now you have more control on the output, cause `next_cursor=10` should always return the same (unless some records are deleted).

**Pros**

- New rows don't affect the result, so no duplicated results when paginating.
- Filtering by an indexed cursor is way faster that using database offset.
- Using previous cursor to avoid duplicating the first elements.

**Cons**

No previous page, although the browser still has them.

No navigating to arbitrary pages (you must know the previous result to know the next ones).

**Paginating Query Builder Results**

There are several ways to paginate items. The simplest is by using the `cursorPaginate` method on the **query builder** or an **Eloquent query**. The `cursorPaginate` method automatically takes care of setting the proper limit and fetching the next or previous elements based on the cursor being viewed by the user. By default, the `cursor` is detected by the value of the page query string argument on the HTTP request. This value is automatically detected by the package taking your custom config into account, and is also automatically inserted into links and meta generated by the paginator.

```
public function index()
{
    $users = DB::table('users')->cursorPaginate();
    return $users;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may solve your problem. It's a custom pagination

In your Blade View File:

```
<!-- pass variable page with a value 
     this generation of your pagination
     should be based to the number of rows
     of your table in the database and not
     static. use foreach for this.
-->
<a href="pagination?page=1">1</a>
...
```

In your Controller:

```
public function pagination(Request $request){
    // set the target page to 0 if page is 1 or null
    // else get the value 
    $targetPage = ($request->input('page') == 1 || !$request->input('page')) ? 0 : ($request->input('page') - 1) ;
    $noOfDataToGet = 10;      

    // get the number of data and skip the data based of target page * number of data        
    $tables = Tables::take($noOfDataToGet)->skip($targetPage * $noOfDataToGet)->get();
}
```

Hope this helps